# Math library design decision: throw exceptions or fail silently

Tags: math, javascript

Say you're designing a math library (in JS) from scratch: the usual *Vector2/3/4*, *Matrix2/3/4*, *Quaternion* and so on (standard stuff for WebGL apps). What would be the best way to handle bad input? (division by zero, inverting a singular matrix, computing the intersection point between 2 parallel lines and so on).

The two ways to deal with this would be to:

- throw exceptions

I know there are plenty who like to know precisely when their code fails - sort of the same people who hate dynamic typing, but I can't help but think of the dreaded *"Error 200: Division by zero"* exceptions that I got so much of in my early days of programming years ago. The only solution was to sprinkle the code with checks to prevent any of these errors. That only made code UGLY. I also can't help but wonder why programming languages nowadays have adopted *+/-Infinity* and *NaN*.

- or to fail silently

In this case, the possible scenarios when trying to execute the line:
`singularMatrix.invert().add(otherMatrix)`
would be:

1. `singularMatrix.invert()` would return `BAD_MATRIX`, and `BAD_MATRIX.add()` would do nothing (and "stop the computation" (JQuery-like))
2. `singularMatrix.invert()` would fail but return itself unchanged and `.add()` would work
3. `singularMatrix.invert()` would fill the matrix with *+/-Infinity* and the computation would continue

I would personally prefer one of the latter options, but I'm totally open to arguments and alternatives (that's why I'm asking here on SO).
I don't know if the "best way" for this sort of thing has been invented yet.

Comment: I agree with @Wyzard's answer to not fail silently. It appears you already made up your mind that the exception approach is tedious for your implementation. That leaves choices #1 and #3 in your second option set. That selection will depend upon how you want to handle the conditions in the calling code, but either is reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NaN and status codes (option 3)**

The IEEE754 standard was created to resolve a lot of these issue in a completely consistent way. For example, 1/0 == +inf, which is a kind of NaN. This standard is baked into processors themselves. It is neither a thrown exception (which would make some simple code very complex) nor a silent failure. You can trace the NaNs all the way back to where they appeared, giving you the debug information you need to fix the bug.

As far as large routines like matrix inversion goes, numerical libraries generally follow the unix convention of returning a status code. In Javascript you can do this by returning an object with a status property.

Taking your example:

```
singularMatrix.invert().add(otherMatrix)
```

If `invert` were to return a matrix object full of NaNs with the status property 'invalid matrix', then `add` can be called and return another matrix full of NaNs.

This permits you to call `invert` and later check whether it was valid; if you use exceptions you have to handle them immediately, and when you want to defer a decision until later, you'll have to set up the same set of properties.

There is still useful information in a matrix that is partially or entirely filled with NaNs - the shape information can be used to create a new matrix to replace a bad initial vector, or known good values can still be used in calculation.

TLDR: Do the NaN thing, and recreate it in matrices.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you do, don't fail silently.  There's no point in continuing the computation if the result is going to be wrong, and you don't want to show an incorrect result to the user and claim that it's correct.  Nothing good can come of that, *especially* in a reusable library where you don't necessarily know what the caller will do with the result.

Throw an exception or return a special value that the caller can check for, such as `undefined`.